# EV SSL cert for custom domain listed as SAN fails to upload

Tags: parse-platform, ssl-certificate

I've been attempting to get a certificate uploaded for a Parse custom domain. It is an EV certificate issued by DigiCert, and appears to be valid. The Parse custom domain is listed as a Subject Alternative Name to the main domain and appears in the certs list of SANs, e.g. CN: www.domain.com, SAN: app.domain.com. The names are identical.

Every attempt to upload results in:

> App's custom domain name must match certificate CN.

Is there a limitation to Parse SSL certificates? Any known workarounds?

Comment: I would also ask on the parse message board for a better chance at getting a reply from the dev team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Parse.com docs, at the end of the section on hosting:

> Multi-domain SSL certificates are not currently supported.

Hopefully this thread will keep someone from making my mistake -- buying an EV Multi-Domain cert and expecting Parse to accept my custom domain defined as a SAN.

Fortunately I'm able to swap my Common Name, and rely on the SANs for friendlier environments.